# An error happens in my wordnet python code: IndexError; List index out of range

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am working on some small code, and the error

> ```
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

always comes after execution of the last line of code, any help?

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet  # this is where you load the wordnet corpus

user_input = input("What should I reverse, user?")  # this is where you get the items for the string

str = user_input  # this is the initial string

stringlength = len(str)  # this is where you calculate length of the list

slicedString = str[stringlength::-1]  # this is where you start slicing

syns = wordnet.synsets(slicedString)  # this gives the reversed word to the dictionary

print(syns[0].definition())  # this prints the meaning (if there is one)
```

I have looked in books for the answer, but nothing is working. (PyCharm Edu 4.0)

Comment: What user input are you using?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `syns` is not a list or tuple of length at least 1. Have you tried printing this variable to see if it contains a value?